# MEF load plugin from directory

Tags: c#, location, mef, .net-assembly

I work with MEF and I am looking how to change the url of the location of plugins by another means that MEF find the plugins, I want to change this line

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\julia\project\project.Plugin.Nav\bin\Debug\NavPlugin.dll")));
```

I want to delete this url because I need to deploy my application in another machine

This is my function :

```
public void AssembleCalculatorComponents()
{
   try
   {
       //var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
       //var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
       //container.ComposeParts(this);
       var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

       catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\yosra\project\project.Plugin.Nav\bin\Debug\NavPlugin.dll")));
       var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

       container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
 }
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: As a side-note: you should not use `throw ex;` in your catch block (this "destroys" the stack trace, i.e. you won't be able to really know where the exception actually happened). If you want to re-throw the exception, just use `throw;` (without specifying the exception again) - or just **don't** catch the exception if you're not doing anything with it at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello again and thanks for your response, so my problem was to load the plugin directly, so i create  a directory and i place my plugins in this folder, so i find this solution

```
public void AssembleCalculatorComponents()
        {


            string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins");
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            //Check the directory exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            string assemblyName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
            Console.WriteLine(assemblyName);
            //Create an assembly catalog of the assemblies with exports
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
                new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.Load(assemblyName)),
                new DirectoryCatalog(path, "*.dll"));

            //Create a composition container
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
```

this is my solution , thinks for all

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [DirectoryCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx) class to have MEF scan a particular directory for assemblies that satisfy your imports.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("."));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

The above will add the base directory the AppDomain uses for locating assemblies (usually the directory holding the executable unless changed with configuration) to the aggregate catalog. You will also probably want to add the current executing assembly, though it is not required.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("."));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

More information on MSDN for DirectoryCatalog: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response,i change for this code `var catalog =new AggregateCatalog();
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"./plugins"));
             var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);` but  not work with me, can you please explains more for me

Answer (score 2):

Two options.

1. Use the current directory as the root for your plugins. Environment.CurrentDirectory should point you in the right direction.
2. Use an app.config to specify a directory for your plugins to be stored in.

Answer (score 1):

If your method *knows of* the type to be instantiated, you can use the `Assembly` property of the `Type` which is typical for *my* *Domain* libraries; otherwise, you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. I am not particularly fond of `GetExecutingAssembly()` or `GetCallingAssembly()` ...:

```
  public void AssembleCalculatorComponents() {
     try {
        var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
     // OR
        asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(TObject).Assembly); // replace TObject with object's actual type
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(asmCatalog);
        // 
        AddDirectoryCatalogs(aggregateCatalog.Catalogs));
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        // assuming this class has the member(s) to be composed.
        container.ComposeParts(this);
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
     }
  }
```

Aside from that, you can add DirectoryCatalogs - either by the `app.config` file, serialized list of directories, etc. Starting off, though, you can designate a default directory in your `app.config` - which is what I recommend. Then, assuming you are using `Settings`:

```
private readonly Settings settings = Settings.Default;

void AddDirectoryCatalogs(ICollection<ComposablePartCatalog> Catalogs agrCatalogs ) {
    agrCatalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(settings.DefaultPath, settings.DefaultPattern));
    // add more directory catalogs
}
```

While using `"."` as the search path is a legitimate shortcut to the executing assembly's directory, keep in mind that all assemblies will be searched for fulfilling parts - i.e., matching `Import`/`Export` objects. Use of specific patterns is my recommendation. Microsoft's examples are not known for being the *best* practices. If you expect any plugin to be suffixed with `Plugin.dll`, make that part of your search pattern.